# Keyboard shortcuts gone from menus in some programs in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard, menu, shortcuts, gvim, inkscape

I have noticed that keyboard shortcuts from GVim and Inkscape are gone from the menus of those programs in Ubuntu 12.04.

In Ubuntu 10.04 these shortcuts were displayed in the menus.

Are there ways to get the keyboard shortcuts back and displayed in the menus or is this an (intended) feature/bug?

Best Wishes

Anders

Comment: **bump** Not to be rude, but does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

This is now a documented Ubuntu bug - you can follow its progress [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/978401) and read about it over [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+question/197498)